# Firefly animation, browser gets slower after a while

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I was checking out the demo of greensock. You can see that the result is a firefly animation, unfortunately the more time passes the slower the browser gets. Even if set to a total of 15-30 dots.

Is there any efficient way to stop the script from accumulating somehow?

```
function RN(x){
    return Math.random()*x;
  }
    var total = 100 ;
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    var target = document.getElementById('container');
    for (i=0; i<total; i++){
        var e = document.createElement('div');
        e.className = "dot";
        e.opacity = 0;
        e.style.left = RN(w)+'px';
        e.style.top = RN(h)+'px';
        target.appendChild(e);
        animm(e);
    }
    function animm(elm){
      TweenMax.killTweensOf(elm);
      TweenMax.to(elm, (RN(80))+40, {
        bezier:{
            curviness:3,
            values:[
                {left:RN(w), top:RN(h)},
                {left:RN(w), top:RN(h)}
            ]
        },
        onComplete:function(){
          TweenMax.delayedCall(RN(2), animm, [elm]);
        }
      });
      TweenMax.to(elm, (RN(4)+2),{
        force3D:true,
        opacity:RN(.7)+.1,
        repeat:-1,
        scale:RN(1.25)+.25,
        yoyo:true,
        ease:Bounce.easeInOut
      });
    };
```

http://codepen.io/maelfyn/pen/GgRLbg

Answer (score 0):

Animate only X and Y properties, which are cheap for browser to render, not left and right. X and Y do not trigger recalculation of layout. Best solution would be proper redistribution of memory usage between CPU and GPU. Use CSS3 animations/transitions, which consume GPU instead of CPU (CPU is standardly used by javascript animations).

Answer (score 0):

**The browser is handling this just fine.** If you change the speed to 3 temporarily you can see that the animation speed is getting slower as the dots settle towards their final destination finally coming to a stop, before starting the next animation.

```
TweenMax.to(elm, 3, {
    bezier:{
        curviness:3,
        values:[
            {left:RN(w), top:RN(h)},
            {left:RN(w), top:RN(h)}
    ]
}
```

You should try playing around with various settings to get the dots to have a more even speed throughout the animation.